# how to generate html test reports in squish using javascript?

Tags: html, report, squish

how to generate html test reports in squish using java script?
I have a test suite in squish and i would like to create a test report in html format. I have developed the test suite in java script.

Answer (score 0):

To generate HTML reports, simply invoke the [`squishrunner`](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.1/rg-cmdline.html#rg-squishrunner-cli) program with the `--reportgen` option, passing `html` as the report generator. For example:

```
squishrunner --testsuite C:\Tests\suite_mysuite --reportgen html,C:\Report\
```